# How to connect an Apache Camel synchronous request/reply endpoint with asynchronous sub-routes

Tags: apache-camel

I'd like to route a webservice request to an InOnly endpoint of a jms queue. Then route a response jms message received from a separate InOnly endpoint back to the webservice client as the response. The webservice request/response is a synchronous InOut pattern, and the sub-routes are asynchronous. What options do I have to achieve this with Camel?

The Camel route here is used to explain my question:

```
String uri={webserice uri}
from(uri)    
    .process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            ServcieRequest req =            
            exchange.getIn().getBody(ServcieRequest.class);                 
            // One option to me is to spawn another route here to route to jms queue...         
            ProducerTemplate template = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
            template.sendBodyAndHeaders("jms:queue:INQueue", req.getPayload(), headers);
            // then need to wait ...until received jms response from the route below        

   }});


from("jms:queue:OUTQueue")
   .process(new Processor() {
       public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
           // received jms response message
           // need to update the exchange data in the above route based on jms message
           // so the final response to the webservice cilent can receive the data ...
       }});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should rely on the request reply mechanism in Camel for this task.
[Camel Doc, Exclusive Fixed Reply Queue](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html#JMS-RequestreplyoverJMSandusinganexclusivefixedreplyqueue)

So I guess the following DSL route does pretty much what you want (if there is no other reason why you should use a InOnly pattern for the JMS part?). Make sure you tune the requestTimeout if you need (as it defaults to 20Sec timeout).

```
from(webserviceURI)
  .inOut().to("jms:queue:INQueue?replyTo=OUTQueue?replyToType=Exclusive");
```

Yes, one other thing. If you run this on several nodes, then you need one exclusive queue per node.

Comment: In terms of coordination of replies then that statement is wrong. Camel uses the standard JMSCorrelationID to map requests and replies. The IDs is auto generated if the user do not explicit configure a correlation id manually.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have tried Petter's scheme and it worked!  As `inOut().to("...` was deprecated, I changed to `.inOut("...`. I also skipped `replyToType` as for some reason it gave error "Invalid destination name - OUTQueue?replyToType=Exclusive" in my Camel version 2.9.1.   Claus is correct on JMSCorrelationID. In fact, I wonder if there is a way for Camel to ignore JMSCorrelationID (I know this is a bit different subject) as in some situations it could be convenient?

Comment: There is a disableReplyTo option. See the Camel JMS documentation: http://camel.apache.org/jms. There is really a lot of details there. Can you mark this questions as answered, now that you got it resolved?

Comment: Now I can see that disableReplyTo may have that effect, or replyToType=Exclusive will certainly ignore JMSCorrelationID checking. Thanks for the answer.